# How communication should be between a JPOS Client and none JPOS-HOST

Tags: java, jpos

I'm working on financial messages transmission, we're tasked to send an ISO-8583 message from One System to another, we decided to manipulate jpos, the problem that occurred is that we the receiver from the other side is not a jpos Server, so it doesn't recognize where the MTI is, where the header is, and stuff like that, to be more clear, it doesn't recognize the jpos **pack** output.

Is there anything we can do? are we obligated to go and modify at our end (jpos's end)?

Comment: Hello, you need to get the specification and find out how messages are delimited to choose or create the appropriate channel, and also find out in which format the message fields are expected to choose or create the appropriate packager.

Many if not most jpos application need to talk to non jpos systems, in fact jpos was created to talk to previous system that obviously weren't based on jPOS.

Comment: OK? WE made some progress understanding how things works, for the channel we're implementing **ASCII_CHANNEL**, for the packager we're using **GenericPackager**, in this case, would the output received by the distant server be an ascii output ?

Comment: ASCII channel only means that it sends the message length as 4 ascii digits. The real packaging depends on how you configured your GenericPackager but you have to research and make sure each field definition is aligned (it has the same format) as what the server expects